# Python speech_recognition using Google Web Speech API not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the Google Web Speech API in Python. I just tried the following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr import pyaudio   r = sr.Recognizer() with sr.Microphone() as source:
    # read the audio data from the default microphone
    print("Speak!")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Recognizing...")
    # convert speech to text
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
    print("You said: ", text)
```

But I get Bad Request 400 Error.

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition request failed: Bad Request
```

All my Python packages are up to date, so what am I missing?

Comment: Here, I can help with this I believe. I think its just a matter of how you told it to work.

Comment: @RedgarTech what do you mean? Any suggestion you may have?

Comment: So sorry. I was writing the answer and I got distracted. Give this a try.

Comment: Also, import the packages in your above program for the program below.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @RedgarTech unfortunately no. Same error. Python 3.7

Comment: I edited my solution with some additional troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the code from Redgar Tech, but with a little change. Not sure if one needs to import from os the import path, but it worked.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
from speech_recognition.recognizers import google

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:

    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
    print(f'User said: {query}\n')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Google didn't Understand.")
```

Answer (score -1):

The first step is to import Speech recognition because it is a dependency. Install by running pip and typing    "pip install SpeechRecognition"
Then `import speech_recognition as sr`

The next step is the actual important part which is where google sr obtains the speech as a query
You do this by creating a function. I chose "takeCommand" as the function
As you can see below, you assign the recognizer to a variable
You open the microphone up with the statement below the variable line
You can only use the microphone when Pyaudio is installed     You do this by typing "pip install pyaudio" in a terminal or the ide terminal
You do require an exception handler incase anything was missed by google.

Create a function `def takeCommand():` and put the following in the function.

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:

    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
    print("User said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Google didn't Understand.")
    return "None"

return query
```

This can be used in many different ways. If any questions come up, please tell me and I can even provide samples of programs featuring this.

***Edit***

This solution will not work unless you are sure of the following:

1. Anti-virus is disabled (if applicable)
2. Firewall or Network Security isn't interfering with things on your PC
3. You confirm that every prerequisite package has been installed for this
   [Speech Recognition API Documentation for Python](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)